# Align text next to a headline

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this has been asked before but I'm not quite sure how to word my search.

I want to have a list of facts, with a headline on the left and the information on the right. This is what I have so far:

[image: This is how I want it to look]

However, if I put too much text on the right, it doesn't stay aligned right but goes under the headline.

[image: Not looking right]

How do I get the text to stay aligned on the right? Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
.about-fact {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #aaa;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.about-headline {
    display: inline-block;      /* Aligns the content to be the same */
    width: 100px;
    float:left;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.about-value {

}
```

Example HTML:

```
<div class="about-fact">
    <div class="about-headline">Profession:</div>
    <div class="about-value">Studying Computer Science at Carleton University</div>
</div>
<div class="about-fact">
    <div class="about-headline">Experience:</div>
    <div class="about-value">Resume</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this css

```
.about-value {
    margin-left: 100px;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k4aQ5/

Answer (score 3):

#### Suggestions

1. Add `overflow: hidden;` to the parent.
2. Remove `inline-block;`.
3. Add `float` and `width` to the `.about-value`.

#### Change CSS to include floats.

```
.about-fact {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #aaa;
    padding: 10px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.about-headline {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.about-value {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer but when the text is long it goes underneath the headline, not next to it. I have to accept the other answer which works for me.

Comment: Hey, you need to specify the width. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's make the markup a bit more semantic first:

```
<dl class="about-facts">
    <dt>Profession:</dt>
    <dd>Studying Computer Science at Carleton University</dd>
    <dt>Experience:</dt>
    <dd>Resume</dd>
</dl>​
```

This requires changes to the CSS as well, of course. Because there's no longer a wrapping `div`, to get the border to extend all the way to the left we need to set `padding-left` not `margin-left`:

```
.about-facts dt {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.about-facts dt {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.about-facts dd {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 120px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #aaa;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ekMZ6/1/